# how to check what is causing webdriver-manager to fail

Tags: angular, protractor, chrome-web-driver, webdriver-manager

I am trying to execute this simple protractor example https://coryrylan.com/blog/introduction-to-e2e-testing-with-the-angular-cli-and-protractor and I am getting

```
webpack: Compiled successfully.
events.js:182
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 123.123.123.123:443
    at Object._errnoException (util.js:1024:11)
    at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1046:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1185:14)
```

As far as I could understand, this is an error caused by failing while updating the webdrive-manager. I tried update manually by myself but I am still getting the same error.

```
PS C:\_pocs\ws_vsc\ng-pokedex-master> npm install -g webdriver-manager
C:\Users\dca\AppData\Roaming\npm\webdriver-manager -> C:\Users\dca\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webdriver-manager\bin\webdriver-manager
+ webdriver-manager@12.0.6
added 93 packages in 7.637s
PS C:\_pocs\ws_vsc\ng-pokedex-master> ng e2e
** NG Live Development Server is listening on localhost:49152, open your browser on http://localhost:49152/ **
Date: 2017-12-27T15:18:27.307Z
Hash: 7b44c1a34c892e7982d9
Time: 11649ms
chunk {about.module} about.module.chunk.js, about.module.chunk.js.map () 5.36 kB  [rendered]
chunk {inline} inline.bundle.js, inline.bundle.js.map (inline) 5.83 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {main} main.bundle.js, main.bundle.js.map (main) 41.1 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {pokemon.module} pokemon.module.chunk.js, pokemon.module.chunk.js.map () 19.3 kB  [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.bundle.js, polyfills.bundle.js.map (polyfills) 199 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.bundle.js, styles.bundle.js.map (styles) 66.4 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.bundle.js, vendor.bundle.js.map (vendor) 3.33 MB [initial] [rendered]
(node:14144) [DEP0022] DeprecationWarning: os.tmpDir() is deprecated. Use os.tmpdir() instead.

webpack: Compiled successfully.
events.js:182
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 123.123.123.123:443
    at Object._errnoException (util.js:1024:11)
    at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1046:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1185:14)
```

and, other tentative

```
PS C:\_pocs\ws_vsc\ng-pokedex-master> webdriver-manager start
webdriver-manager: using global installed version 12.0.6
[16:20:31] W/start - the out_dir path C:\Users\dca\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium does not exist, run webdriver-manager update
PS C:\_pocs\ws_vsc\ng-pokedex-master> webdriver-manager update
webdriver-manager: using global installed version 12.0.6
[16:20:52] I/file_manager - creating folder C:\Users\dca\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium
events.js:182
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 123.123.123.123:443
    at Object._errnoException (util.js:1024:11)
    at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1046:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1185:14)
```

I don't think it will be relevant but just in case here is the package.json from above project. I tried both "protractor": "~5.1.1" and 5.1.2

```
{
  "name": "ng-pokedex",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "lint": "sass-lint && ng lint",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false",
    "e2e": "protractor",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build:prod": "npm run lint && ng build --prod --stats-json",
    "deploy": "npm run build:prod && firebase deploy",
    "bundle-report": "webpack-bundle-analyzer dist/stats.json"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.1.2",
    "@angular/common": "^5.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.1.2",
    "@angular/core": "^5.1.2",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.1.2",
    "@angular/http": "^5.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.1.2",
    "@angular/router": "^5.1.2",
    "@angular/service-worker": "^5.1.2",
    "blueprint-css": "2.4.2",
    "core-js": "^2.5.3",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.6.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.1.2",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.1.2",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.95",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.3.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.1",
    "sass-lint": "1.12.1",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "~2.4.2",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "2.9.0"
  }
}
```

Other thing just came to my mind would be that I had wrong proxy configuration but I can successfully run npm install so I don't think this will explain my issue. BTW, here is

```
H:\>npm config list
; cli configs
metrics-registry = "https://registry.npmjs.org/"
scope = ""
user-agent = "npm/5.5.1 node/v8.8.1 win32 x64"

; userconfig C:\Users\dca\.npmrc
http-proxy = "http://XXX.vm.mycompany.net:3128/"
https-proxy = "http://XXX.vm.mycompany.net:3128/"
proxy = "http://XXX.vm.mycompany.net:3128/"

; builtin config undefined
prefix = "C:\\Users\\dca\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm"

; node bin location = C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe
; cwd = H:\
; HOME = C:\Users\dca
; "npm config ls -l" to show all defaults.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause is your network behind a proxy and the proxy you configured for NPM won't take effect on webdriver-manager (webdriver-manager won't read the proxy setting for NPM)

**Option 1**: add proxy every time in webdriver-manager command

`webdriver-manager update --proxy=http://XXX.vm.mycompany.net:3128`

Note: you also need to add the proxy when execute `webdriver-manager start`

**Option 2**: configure proxy in Environment Variable, then you no need to add proxy in weddriver-manager command.

Add below environment variable to user environment variable (Current login User, Not System Environment Variable)

`HTTP_PROXY = http://XXX.vm.mycompany.net:3128/` 
`HTTPS_PROXY = http://XXX.vm.mycompany.net:3128/` 
`NO_PROXY = .mycompany.net,localhost,127.0.0.1`

Note: after do that, the proxy setting will impact every command/program(will access network) executed from command window

Comment: this is new for me "you also need to add the proxy when execute webdriver-manager start". I spent between 8 or 14 hours struggling to get this working also believing that it was somehow related to proxy. And everything I ried after read a lot was only driving me to a new error. I don't know the reason but after I uninstall the node from my Windows and try it by firstly install nvm and then install both node and npm throw nvm I believe it fix all issues. I guess I had some incompatibilty version issue that was properly arranged by nvm (not sure). BTW, you really answered my original question

Comment: Since the later verions of webdriver-manager (may be since 12.0.6), 'webdriver-manger start' will query which is the latest version of webdriver and selenium standalone server, it's designed as this on later version. so it need to access network even you already had updated the latest version to local.