# Set alternative CDN for ChromeDriver binaries on @angular/cli

Tags: protractor, angular-cli, webdriver-manager

I'm working on a project based on Angular (`5.0.0`). As I am behind a proxy, I want to specify an internal CDN where ChromeDriver is hosted.

My `.npmrc` file contains the following property:
`chromedriver_cdnurl=http://my-internal-cdn/chromedriver/`
(also tested with `alternate_cdn`, without changes).

My command to run e2e is `npm run e2e` (which runs `ng e2e --proxy-config proxy.conf.json`) and fails with the following error:

> webpack: Compiled successfully. events.js:182
>         throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>         ^
>
> Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com
>   chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com:443
>       at errnoException (dns.js:53:10)
>       at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:95:26) npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! whiteapp-angular@1.0.0
>   e2e: `ng e2e --proxy-config proxy.conf.json`

I'm not sure how I can tell to ng-cli to use this property so webdriver-manager can download the binaries from an internal CDN and not from `chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com`. Any idea?

I've not found anything interesting regarding this point in the [protractor configuration](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts).

Thanks.

Comment: I think it duplicate to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48026467/ng-e2e-is-failling-probably-in-reason-of-proxy-but-ng-serve-and-ng-test-ar/48033244#48033244, if not please tell me.

Comment: Hi @yong Thanks. The issue is quite related but it's not exactly the same thing. On your pointer, the question is "how can I use my proxy settings for webdriver manager". I don't want to use the proxy but force webdriver-manager to look in an internal CDN for binaries.

Comment: Hi, I think this may be a little dumb but, how did you create your internal CDN. I wanted also to create my own since company proxy is causing problems, I was thinking with our Jfrog repository but i am unsure what the type of the repository should be, also how it would be structured

Comment: @Mr.O on my context, our CDN is a simple web server powered by nginx. You "just" need to respect the sub-directories structure expected by the module, like `chromedriver/{version}/*.zip`

Comment: Hi @RomainLinsolas, thank you for the quick reply. So basically a reverse proxy that would point to the chromedriver urls according but passing through your company proxy correct?

Comment: Hi @Mr.O That's indeed possible, but in my context, it's simple server that serves the binaries, hosted internally.

Comment: @RomainLinsolas alright thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 3):

**Option 1)** modify the cdnurl in `node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/config.json`

```
{
  "cdnUrls": {
    "selenium": "https://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/",
    "chromedriver": "https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/",
    "geckodriver": "https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/",
    "iedriver": "https://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/",
    "androidsdk": "http://dl.google.com/android/"
  }
}
```

**Option 2)** webdriver-manager has a cli option: `--alternate_cdn` for change cdn url, you can check by run `webdriver-manager --help`.  But you use `ng e2e` which can't accept `--alternate_cdn` from command line

Comment: It seems --alternate_cdn options is not working. See https://github.com/angular/webdriver-manager/issues/214

Comment: Regarding option 1. For webdriver-manager 12.1.7 installed globally by protractor (on Windows) node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/built/config.json is used (note the "built" folder). It's confusing because there also exists (a copy ?) config.json file with the same contents in node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager